# How to add a space between two text in SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add space in this SQL text?

```
ISNULL('phone:  '  + [phone],' ') + 'some space' +  ISNULL('email: ' +[email],' ')  +
```

What can be used in the place of 'some space ' so that space is put in between the texts ? any help , thank you.

EDITED
I want the phone and email displayed far apart eachother may be 100px in between them

SPACE function works in SQL but not in browser. what is wrong?

Comment: What are you displaying this on?  the easy way is to make it two columns

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL has `||` for concatenation, some products have `concat()` others have `+`.

Comment: if i want them to concat for my case what can be used?

Comment: i am using MS SQL SERVER

Comment: @abrahamd. Then [edit] your question to add the [tag:sql-server] tag. Done for you by Barbaros.

Comment: @abrahamd.for concat SELECT CONCAT(ISNULL('phone:  '  + [phone],' '), CHAR(9),ISNULL('email: ' +[email],' ')) AS Info

Comment: @Michel Concat not found in 2005 version. I'm on it.

Comment: If you're counting "pixels" then you should probably put phone and email into their own columns like @Hogan suggested.

Comment: i need white pace anyways. Pixels i mention for example

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL Server.  Your issue is with how the text is displayed in a web browser.  As you've said yourself, "SPACE works in Sql".

Answer (score 5):

Instead of just writing some space, literally use spaces

`('phone:  '  + [phone],' ') + 'some space' +  ('email: ' +[email],' ')  +`

to
`('phone:  '  + [phone],' ') + '         ' +  ('email: ' +[email],' ')  +`

Comment: if i want a wider space in between

Comment: @abrahamd. then use more spaces

Comment: @abrahamd. Needs to answer Hogan's question. For example if this is being displayed on a website, the multiple spaces will collapse, no matter how many you use.

Comment: @Richard i agree it is true

Comment: @abrahamd. Please edit your question to clarify the scenario.

Comment: Instead of trying to count the number of spaces it would be easier to use REPLICATE. :)

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the documentation for Replicate. I always forget about it but there is also a [SPACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/space-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function for replicating a number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear if this is what you're asking but, depending on your variant of SQL, you might not be able to concatenate text with "+".

Rather there is generally some flavor of the concat() or concatenate() function that serves this purpose.

eg. concat(isnull(concat('phone: ', [phone]),' '), 'some space')... etc

Comment: i want to put them appear some what far each other may be 100px

Answer (score 0):

Use ASCII code for horizontal tab which is CHAR(9) along with CONCAT function.
You can also do a function with a loop to set your spacing

```
DECLARE @tabSpacing varchar(50)='';
DECLARE @counter int = 50;
WHILE @counter>0
BEGIN
    SET @tabSpacing+=CHAR(9);
    SET @counter-=1;
END

SELECT CONCAT(ISNULL('phone:  '  + [phone],' '),@tabSpacing,ISNULL('email: ' +[email],' ')) AS Info FROM Users
```

Comment: sorry my question how to add a white space between phone and email

Comment: i want them displayed far apart

Comment: @abrahamd.i have edited my solution which may satisfy your needs.

Comment: it works right in SQL. But browser do not keep the space

Comment: your code works in sql not in browser. only this display space in browser.
[COL1] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + [COL2] but is good in sql? is it right way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT LTRIM(COALESCE(' phone:  '  + [phone], '') + COALESCE(' email: ' + [email], ''))
```

This will return one or the other (or both) with no leading spaces.

Comment: i want phone and email displayed a little bit far apart

Comment: i want to put about 100px white space in the

Comment: i found  &nbsp; &nbsp; still works with SQL. But require much of it. and i don't think this is the right way. there must be some way to add white space in sql. i need help

Answer (score 0):

If this is being displayed on a website, then one option is to make sure there is a clear 1-pixel gif on the website, and add the `img` tag for that gif and style it with the amount of horizontal space that you want.

But then I haven't done web dev in so long that 1-pixel gifs could be totally passe today for all I know.

Comment: Browsers are made to ignore multiple empty spaces.   I don't know why, they just are.

Answer (score 0):

It may help someone when a need arises. My question was solved this way

```
DECLARE @wider_space NVARCHAR(50);
SET @wider_space = '& nbsp ; & nbsp ; & nbsp ; & nbsp;& nbsp ; & nbsp ;& nbsp ; & nbsp ;';
---avoid spaces when used 
ISNULL('Phone:  '  + [phone] + @wider_space,' ')  +  ISNULL('Email: ' +[email] + @wider_space,' ')  + ...
```

and continues like this to concat 6 columns together.